# When does "part" mean "quarter"?

Tags: synonyms, history

> ‘Behind us in the caves of the Deep are three parts of the folk of Westfold, old and young, children and women,’ said Gamling. ‘But great store of food, and many beasts and their fodder, have also been gathered there.’

JRR Tolkien, *The Lord of the Rings*, Volume 2: “The Two Towers”, Book Three, Chapter VII, “Helm’s Deep”

By *three parts*, Gamling means “three parts of four”, or “three quarters”. Or, at least, so I assume. Why do I assume that? It’s an assumption built in so deeply that I have *no idea* where it comes from. Is it a correct assumption? How long has the assumption that everything has four parts (or, rather, that a *part* means a quarter) been around? And is it still safe to use language that way today?

Comment: I have never heard such an assumption. All Gaul, for example, is divided into only three parts, not four. :-) I think that if you are counting parts in this sense, how many slices of the whole, you must specify the total number for it to make sense. Of course it's quite meaningful to talk about parts with no relationship to a percentage of the total. If I say, "I replaced three parts in my car today", that says nothing about what percentage of the car was replaced. It is very unlikely that it was 75%.

Comment: @Jay. The point is that neither Gamling nor Tolkien ever give any indication of the number of parts, so it must be implicit. And I automatically (from somewhere) inferred four. Is that a safe assumption?

Comment: One assumption I can imagine is that you read "quarts" for "parts" subconciously. Otherwise, since you say you got it from "somewhere", are you sure the book doesn't mention "somewhere" how many parts the folk are divided in?

Comment: @MrLister. I'm pretty sure the book never mentions that. I'll come back to you when I've finished the chapter. And "quarts" isn't really part of my vocabulary, so I doubt that's it either.

Comment: I'm guessing your assumption comes from a few paragraphs up where Elkenbrand "was retreating hither with all that is left of the best Riders of Westfold".  That is the other missing part. (ref: http://www.iment.com/maida/tv/lordoftherings/twotowersetext.htm)

Comment: @TRiG: I have heard of such a usage. Both Alexandre Dumas ("My dear fellow," replied Danglars, "you are three parts drunk ...") and Bertrand Russell (''To fear love is to fear life, and those who fear life are already three parts dead.'') use the expression idiomatically.

Comment: There's some plausibility to FumbleFingers assertion that the phrasing may imply one remaining part. But I'll restate that I am not aware of any general assumption in English about the number of "parts" that make a whole. Highly-regarded as Tolkien is, I wouldn't take one ambiguous statement from him and draw detailed conclusions from it. Maybe he made a mistake. Maybe he was being deliberately ambiguous. Etc. I think that's why we have a word like "parts", precisely because it can be used for any number of divisions, unlike "quarters" or "halves", etc.

Comment: But popular usage can foist different meanings onto words. A _baker's dozen_ is accepted as not meaning 12. 'Three parts' can either mean _3 out of a specified or unspecified total number of portions_, **or** _3/4_ (often used loosely for _almost_ or _largely_).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's not that the word *part* has any direct connection with *quarter*. Tolkien's usage is just a variant on the same trope that gives us...

> [possession is nine **parts/points/tenths** of the law](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/36390/)

If Tolkien had written *"**four** parts of the folk"* (unlikely, I know), it would have meant *four **fifths***. Once you specify how many parts you *have*, the implication is there's *one more unaccounted for*.

---

But I do think *three* is a good number for these contexts - *three **quarters*** is a familiar fraction, *two* is too small for any expression emphasising scale, and *four fifths* is getting complicated. We're much more likely to say [three parts drunk](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22three%20parts%20drunk%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) or [three sheets to the wind](http://www.word-detective.com/2009/06/three-sheets-to-the-wind/), rather than [four](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22kindness%20is%20ninety-nine%20parts%20of%20what%20passes%20for%20wisdom%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbo=d&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22four%20parts%20drunk%22&oq=%22four%20parts%20drunk%22&gs_l=serp.3...38164.39975.0.40322.6.6.0.0.0.0.77.315.6.6.0...0.0...1c.1.fy26igqWmLY&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=65087f4ec2c01d51&bpcl=38897761&biw=1323&bih=866) or [five](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22each%20sail%20had%20four%20sheets%20at%20the%20corners%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbo=d&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22five%20sheets%20to%20the%20wind%22&oq=%22five%20sheets%20to%20the%20wind%22&gs_l=serp.3...4259.9887.0.10577.23.23.0.0.0.0.92.1173.23.23.0...0.0...1c.1.k5Xo5jCBv-g&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=65087f4ec2c01d51&bpcl=38897761&biw=1323&bih=866).

Comment: Oh. Yes. Duh. I feel a bit silly now.

Comment: @TRiG: Well, it's far from obvious unless you see it! I'm pretty sure I'm right (that explanation works for me, anyway!), but I'm probably stretching things a bit to call it a "trope", since I can't think of any similar constructions using numbers other than three (of four) and nine (of ten).

Comment: ...but here's [kindness is ninety-nine parts of what passes for wisdom](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=DsoCAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA72&dq=%22kindness+is+ninety-nine+parts+of+what+passes+for+wisdom%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=c4m2UJzlD6iq0AWjwYDQDw&ved=0CDIQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22kindness%20is%20ninety-nine%20parts%20of%20what%20passes%20for%20wisdom%22&f=false) to back me up!

Comment: The way I read it is that a certain specified group is three parts and then there's another group specified. One would assume they're the last quarter as nothing else is said about this fraction. Three quarters is also a good idiom or whatever you call it for something that is substantial, a good round number majority.

Comment: If (as you assert) "n parts" always represents the fraction n/(n+1), how should we interpret a recipe that instructs "to one part flour, add ...".?

Comment: @Fortiter: I don't assert that "n parts" *always* represents any particular fraction of the whole. What I'm saying is that *if "n" is greater than 2*, and *no other parts are specified*, there is a standard "trope" based on the principle that the number of additional unspecified parts is in fact ***one***. So in the unlikely event the recipe said to mix an *unspecified* amount of milk with *"three parts flour"*, you could reasonably assume it meant *"with **one** part milk"*.

Comment: Thank'ee. Also used as a basis for [an answer of mine elsewhere](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/74483).