# Expression for the advantage of being in possession of disputed goods in a civil suite?

Tags: latin, legalese

Some time (years?) ago I saw (In fact it might have been in a comic, possibly Zits.) an expression/proverb that basically said that being in possession of a disputed goods meant that a civil law suit/quarrel was almost won before it had begun. Anyone know what idiom am talking about and can remind me?

NB: I am not sure if it was in English or Latin. If possible I would prefer a latin answer.

Edit: with this answer I found the comic strip where I thought I read it first http://www.thecomicstrips.com/store/add.php?iid=90971

I also found a corresponding latin phrase, *uti possidetis, ita possideatis* (are there any better idioms in latin?), which is more useful since I am not gonna use this expression in an English context.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The expression that comes to mind is

> Possession is nine-tenths of the law.

From the [Free Dictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Possession+is+nine-tenths+of+the+law):

> **possession is nine-tenths of the law**:
>
> Custody presumes ownership. The basis of this legal maxim that comes
>   down from the 17th-century is the commonsense observation that if you
>   have control of something, chances are better than average that it's
>   yours. Lawyers term it a rebuttable presumption: ownership is
>   recognized unless disproved by someone holding a more valid claim. The
>   phrase started life as “possession is nine points of the law,” which
>   referred to possession's satisfying nine out of eleven factors that
>   constituted absolute ownership. However, “nine-tenths” entered popular
>   usage to reflect the idea that custody is 90 percent of legal
>   ownership.

Comment: "Custody presumes ownership" was enshrined in law as **adverse possession**, that is a doctrine under which a person in possession of land owned by someone else may acquire valid title to it, so long as certain common law requirements are met, and the adverse possessor is in possession for a sufficient period of time.

Answer (score 2):

Nouveau Petit Larousse: p.1125 (English paraphrase)

> **Beati possidentes**
>     *happy are those who possess*
>      A phrase made fashionable  by the prince de Bismark; it means if you want to claim
>   ownership of a country you must take possession of it first.

Answer (score 0):

"Possession is nine-tenths of the law."  The definitive exposition may be found in the [archives](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/36390/where-does-the-phrase-possession-is-nine-points-nine-tenths-of-the-law-c) of this site.

Comment: What does that mean?

Comment: Sorry, still don't get it.  Your earlier answer references the Free Dictionary.  I referenced an even earlier answer on this site, which doesn't reference the Free Dictionary.  Maybe it's because I've been up all night, but I fail to see the circularity.

Comment: So there's nothing "self-referential" at all, right?  And you had to "hedge," why exactly?  Our posts cyber-crossed as indicated by the answer times.  Is there something you'd like me to do about it?  Delete my answer?  Move it to a comment?

Comment: Ah, I finally get it!  The "possession" obtained by an earlier post is more important than the information conveyed in a later one.  Delete away, something you could have done an hour ago.