# Does 'in possession of' imply ownership?

Tags: word-usage

Wiktionary has one the definitions of *possession* as ownership, which I agree that as a simple verb, I **posses** is tantamount to I **own, have**. However, the phrase "in one's possession" doesn't effectively or necessarily hold the same meaning for me. It simply implies that something is with you, but not necessarily yours, which is why it often lends itself to accounts of having illicit or stolen property or materials on one's person or in one's home, etc. Wiktionary further cites the following examples under the definition of **ownership**:

> The car is in my possession.
>
> I'm in possession of the car.

This has led to some confusion on a language site I frequent, where one of the users, a Russian, has attempted to use "being in possession of a [type of car - let's say...] Maserati" to translate what amounts to "owning a Maserati" in Russian. Are *owning* and *being in possession of* interchangeable?

Comment: There's simply no difference between the terms. "In possession of" means ownership.

Comment: Thank you, Josh. So if we have the slogan: "Owning a Jaguar is a sheer joy," we could change it to "Being in possession of a Jaguar is a sheer joy" with no change in meaning?

Comment: Yes, although you'd sound slightly old-fashioned.

Comment: @CocoPop There is most definitely a change in meaning.

Comment: I stand corrected - as Lambie states, there does seem to be a difference in the legal sense. But I maintain that in a neutral context, or in the context of "...is a sheer joy", the two are identical.

Comment: No only the legal sense, Josh. I could see a police report saying: The suspect owns a Jaguar, which his sister is currently in possession of while he is abroad." This does not imply ownership. Do you agree?

Comment: @Lambie: I agree, I think our Josh answered to quickly.

Comment: @JoshFriedlander: For one thing, if you were found in possession of stolen goods, by definition they belong to someone else. Furthermore, the person who loads your new Jaguar onto a truck and drives it across the country is in possession of your Jaguar until it reaches your home. So sorry, Josh, your blanket definition is full of holes :)

Comment: Well, these are still all referring to cases of theft or misappropriation. But I'm outgunned here; I won't keep arguing the point. :)

Comment: Not the Jaguar transporter. I think that's a very valid example. The car is yours, but it's with him until it gets to you. No?

Comment: Hmm. I guess so. The most I could say is that possession and ownership can sometimes be separate, but unless that is made explicit most English speakers would assume them to be the same. Thus if I said "I'm in possession of a large fortune" and was actually just its custodian, I would certainly be misleading you!

Comment: Exactly. Another great example!

Comment: Statistically, the answer is yes 9 times out of 10 :)

Answer (score 3):

Here's proof for your "Russian": To be in possession of stolen goods. If to possess meant to own there, that phrase would not make sense. The legal phrase is /to be in possession of/some thing.  You can be in possession of something and then, you do not own it. Have ownership of it.

That said, the VERB: I possess a car does commonly mean I have a car. **It can mean I own a car but actually does not legally mean: I own a car**.

Do not confuse the legal meaning of /to be in  possession of/ with the verb to possess or to own. In common parlance, one would not say "I am in possession of a car" to just mean I have a car or I own a car.

With the verb possess, both **can mean ownership**: I own a car, I possess a car. But possess can merely mean; I have a car, without reference to ownership.

Sometimes, in legal matters, you are in possession of property (not stolen) that you have been given legal use of: that is called, usufruct.  You are allowed to possess it and use it but you are not its legal owner. This kind of legal arrangement is often seen with property in wills where a person is allowed to make use of a property during his or lifetime but they have not actually inherited it. They do not own it.

Comment: Thank you, Lambie. You have basically confirmed exactly what I tried to explain to my friend. Funny enough, he cited an example about being in possession of silverware and I suggested that it could be used legally, i.e. in reference to settling an estate amongst siblings. Great answer!

Comment: Yes, the reason I was able to answer your question is that I do a lot of legal translation and have had to reflect on this quite a bit. Cheers,

Comment: Another subtle difference is that we can sometimes *possess* what we **cannot** *own* – specifically, I possess a husband and four children, but I would not say I "own" them (although I do *own* them in the sense that I admit to them...most of the time).

Comment: Yes, indeed. I agree. I thought I had said that.

Comment: @1006a - You possess 5 people? Are you a demon with multiple personality disorder? I'm not sure I've ever heard "possess" used for people other than either the demon sense or the slavery sense.

Comment: @AndyT It's a slightly old-fashioned usage, but examples like ["he now possessed two children and a wife"](https://books.google.com/books?id=J1E2kDXn5wAC&lpg=PA68&dq=%22possessed%20two%20children%22&pg=PA68#v=onepage&q=%22possessed%20two%20children%22&f=false) or (He) ["had been married twice before, and was already in possession of three children, one from his first marriage and two from his second"](https://www.lrb.co.uk/v24/n11/colm-toibin/how-to-be-a-wife) are not that remarkable.

Comment: Yes, and there it is not ownership, is it? It just means: he now had.

Comment: Possession is nine-tenths of the law: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/36390/where-does-the-phrase-possession-is-nine-points-nine-tenths-of-the-law-c

Comment: Yes, exactly. There's some overlap, but the two words are not really interchangeable. (Just to be clear, I wasn't criticizing your very good answer, just expanding a little bit outside of the legal arena.)